# I'm coding a discord bot and making a verification system, but something weird is happening

Tags: discord.js

```
    const quiz = [
        {
            "question": "What color is the sky?",
            "answer": "blue"
        },
        {
            "question": "How many letters are there in the alphabet?",
            "answer": "26"
        }
    ];
    const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
    const user = message.author
    let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Mrrocketman10s Official Verification System')
        .setDescription('Makes sure that you are a human')
        .addField('Username: ', user.username)
        .addField('Account created at: ', user.createdAt.toLocaleDateString())
        .addField("To verify answer the following question.", item.question)
        .setThumbnail()
    if(!item){
        console.log("Question and answer doesn't exist")
        return false
    }

    const filter = response => {
        return item.answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase();
    };
        message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => { 
                    message.reply("Great! You are now verified!").then(user.member.addRole(role)); 
                }) 
                .catch(collected => { 
                    message.reply("Looks like you didn't get the correct answer, the correct answer is " + item.answer)
                });
        });
        
    }
```

this is the code I need help with, and so what it does is it's supposed to make sure that you are human by making you reply to the question, for example: "What color is the sky" but if you respond blue it would say "Great! You are now verified!" and then say "Looks like you didn't get the correct answer, the correct answer is blue" even though you wrote the correct answer, it doesn't even give you the verified role either
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCwuI.png)

Comment: Check the error passed to the `catch` callback (as the `collected` argument), it should indicate why the message wasn't sent.

Comment: Perhaps the error comes from the bot not being able to add a role? Maybe user.member is not defined?

Comment: Ok I see where you defined `user`, and `Discord.User`, which is returned by message.author, does not have a member property. The way you do this is:
`const user = message.member` instead of `message.author`. Do not do `user.member` for this as message.member already returns the guildMember! Also, I do not see where `role` is defined when you add role to member? Maybe you meant `myRole`

Comment: No matter if I use message.member or not it keeps saying that if I reply with the correct answer it says that its both right and wrong for example:
"Great! You are now verified"
"Looks like you didn't get the answer, the correct answer is blue"

Comment: AHA! I got the error, it says "cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things that you will need to fix in your code:

First, is that you declare a variable `myRole` but you never actually use it to assign the role in your code.

Second, is how you add the role.

```js
user.member.addRole(myRole);
```

There seems to be no `addRole` method for a `GuildMember`, as of `Discord.js` v12. What I recommend doing instead is this:

```js
member.roles.add(myRole).catch(console.error);
```

Third, you'll have to check if the `response` message comes from the `message.author` as well, or else someone else may answer and the bot will recognize it as correct.

```js
const filter = response => {
    return item.answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase() && response.author == message.author;
};
```

Lastly, and the most trivial, you added a curly bracket that would cause a syntax error. You only have to delete a curly bracket and everything's fixed.

---

Side note: I think the `if (!item)` section is extraneous so I just removed it.

---

Code:

```js
const quiz = [
    {
        "question": "What color is the sky?",
        "answer": "blue"
    },
    {
        "question": "How many letters are there in the alphabet?",
        "answer": "26"
    }
];
const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
const user = message.author;
const member = message.guild.member(user);
let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Mrrocketman10s Official Verification System')
    .setDescription('Makes sure that you are a human')
    .addField('Username: ', user.username)
    .addField('Account created at: ', user.createdAt.toLocaleDateString())
    .addField("To verify answer the following question.", item.question)
    .setThumbnail()

//removed if (!item) check

const filter = response => {
    //added an extra parameter to check if the user responding is the original author
    return item.answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase() && response.author == message.author;
};

message.channel.send(embed).then(() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            //modified section here
            message.reply("Great! You are now verified!").then(member.roles.add(myRole).catch(console.error));
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.reply("Looks like you didn't get the correct answer, the correct answer is " + item.answer)
        });
});
```

---

Resources:

1. [Understanding how to use roles](https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles)
2. [Discord.js - GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)